# What should I do when I see blank screen?

Tags: troubleshooting, software-center

i was installing an application using ubuntu software center and screen went blank i waited a while but nothing appearing no desktop so pretty much expected result is that i rebooted manually please correct this or tell me what should i do,iam not running any screensavers nor
does the virtual console work

Comment: STOP! HAMMERTIME?!

Comment: @garbagecollector: Why to flag it as screensaver when he is saying that he is NOT running a screensaver?. I remove the tag as I felt that it was a mistake.

Comment: @Javier he had that there from the beginning, I assumed it was there for a reason. probably for the best. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**REISUB time!!!**

Just press ALT+Pet Sys and type slowly [REISUB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key), one key at time. If it happens often you should probably investigate why is it happening. Ubuntu (and linux) is supposed to be rock-solid because it's usually rock-solid ;). This behaviour is anything but normal.